# Wordpress date_query using date range to get previopus 3 months posts

Tags: wordpress

Hope someone can help

I am using this bit of code to query posts in wordpress:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'cat' => array (2, 531), // 2 is category for Archived Posts, 531 is category for Archived Competitions
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'before' => '1 month ago',
    ),
    array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'after'  => '3 month ago',
    )
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

Now it returns posts from December and November last year, whereas I actually want to return posts from December to October, if I change the 'after' to '4 month ago' it returns posts from August to December. Can anyone enlighten me with regard to showing the previous 3 months posts only

Thanks

Comment: `3 month ago` should work the way you expect, are you sure that you have posts in October to return?  This is a [useful tool](http://strtotime.co.uk/) that will tell you the date that is being used with a given string

Comment: Thanks I did check and I do have posts for October but they are the begining so wouldn't get picked up as strictly they are over 3 months ago to the day. I have changed the published date to 31sty so it does now pick them up. Can anyone suggest a date_query that would allow me to get them from the 1st of 3 months ago. It gets tricky as at this time of the year you are crossing Years as well as trying to go back x months! Thanks for the tool, very helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your posts are at the beginning of the month you need to change your query to the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat' => array (2, 531), // 2 is category for Archived Posts, 531 is category for Archived Competitions
    'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'before' => 'last day of 1 month ago',
    ),
    array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'after'  => 'first day of 3 months ago',
    )
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

Using those values will always return the last/first days of the month.

Comment: That is awesome, looks like its working perfectly! thanks for the answer, it had been bugging me and couln't find it in teh Codex at all or anywhere on the Web.

Comment: No problem.  `WP_Query` uses [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like syntax so you can look for interesting ways to generate dates on that page.